# Opposite of "Sugar Daddy": A young person supporting an older person (financially, materially, sexually)

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, slang, antonyms

I have done quite a bit of searching, no result. Is there a term for the young equivalent of a "Sugar Daddy/Momma"? Not a "Sugar Baby", but a young person who does what a "Sugar Daddy" typically would do (give financial support, buy material necessities and auxiliaries, often for sexual favours in return).

Comment: My immediate thought was _lemon son_, but I don't think that would work too well, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on context I would use *gerontophile*, as per OED:

> loving or favouring old people, esp. old men; desiring sexual relations with old people."

Answer (score 1):

Sugar Honey - Younger Female

Sugar Bear - Younger Male

Comment: Can you explain with references to support the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't assume that there is an established term for this. It is not so common a practice.

"Sugar daddy" is itself a fairly new and non-standard phrase. If it is a term that you want then I invite you to use any that sounds right. "Sugar baby" would suffice, given appropriate context, to convey your meaning.

Comment: A "sugar baby" is someone receiving the support of a sugar daddy/mama.

Comment: I agree that this question is probably going to require coining, or at least expanding upon, a phrase, and your "sugar baby" sounds good to me.  My/your/his/her "low-mileage ride" might also work.

Comment: @PapaPoule - that is just... _wrong_.  I like it.

Comment: What makes you think that "sugar daddy" is "non-standard"?  And what's "fairly new"?  I can find an example in print that's one hundred years old.

Comment: @deadrat I would consider post-20th Century "fairly new", in relative terms, for linguistic constructs.

Comment: @JohnB I see that you are right. Good point. So instead, I'd suggest something descriptive, simple, and semi-established, like "older escort" and "younger patron".

Answer (score -1):

There's no term for it that's accepted readily as it's not common, so feel free to coin a new term. My vote goes to "Daddy Diaper" because of the dependency aspect and alliteration.

Comment: _Daddy Diaper_ conjures up a **very** different image for me, involving an incontinent octogenarian in a nursing home…

Answer (score -1):

How about *sugar cubs* for younger men?

I don't like these answers about geriatrics. It could be a 25 year-old man and a   31 year-old woman: 6 years is not a big deal regardless of who is older (once both are consenting adults).